# How to convert a CLLocationManager method to a block in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

I have a problem in converting a CCLocationManager method to a block.
My CLLocationManager method looks like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    }
    else{NSLog(@"current location is nil");};
}
```

I am trying to convert this method to a block but having difficulty in trying to do so. Kind of new to objective c and ios development.

what I am doing is something like this:

```
double (^getSpeed)(*CLLocation, *CLLocation) = ^(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
        {
            NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
            CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
            mSpeed = currentLocation.speed;
            }
            else{NSLog(@"current location is nil");};
            return mSpeed;
        };
```

but it gives me an error saying that it expects an expression in the first line of block. What does it mean?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

//    1. Declare methods and blocks in .h file like this

```
    typedef void (^currentLocation)(CLLocation *currentLocation);
    // Create property using typedef
    @property (strong) currentLocation objBlock;
    - (void)updateCurrentLocation:(currentLocation)completionBlock;
```

//    2. in delegate method be like this

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    _objBlock(location);
    [locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locManager = nil;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)updateCurrentLocation:(currentLocation)completionBlock {
    _objBlock = completionBlock;
}
```

//    3. Calling would be like this, when ever location get called block will get trigger.

```
    [self updateCurrentLocation:^(CLLocation *currentLocation) {
        NSLog(@"%@", currentLocation);
    }];
```

Comment: I agree but it could not return anything. Basically I am trying to write a block inside another function that would return me a speed

Comment: If "didUpdateLocations" delegate method is getting called "updateCurrentLocation" must return the location. Check delegate is calling or not. In the block it self can calculate what ever you want of course speed.